# How to add columns for animal passage in R

Tags: r, detection, passage

I am trying to summarize our detection data in a way that I can easily see when an animal moves from one pool to another. Here is an example of one animal that I track

```
    tibble [22 x 13] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
     $ Receiver     : chr [1:22] "VR2Tx-480679" "VR2Tx-480690" "VR2Tx-480690" "VR2Tx-480690" ...
     $ Transmitter  : chr [1:22] "A69-9001-12418" "A69-9001-12418" "A69-9001-12418" "A69-9001-12418" ...
     $ Species      : chr [1:22] "PDFH" "PDFH" "PDFH" "PDFH" ...
     $ LocalDATETIME: POSIXct[1:22], format: "2021-05-28 07:16:52" ...
     $ StationName  : chr [1:22] "1405U" "1406U" "1406U" "1406U" ...
     $ LengthValue  : num [1:22] 805 805 805 805 805 805 805 805 805 805 ...
     $ WeightValue  : num [1:22] 8.04 8.04 8.04 8.04 8.04 8.04 8.04 8.04 8.04 8.04 ...
     $ Sex          : chr [1:22] "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" ...
     $ Translocated : num [1:22] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ Pool         : num [1:22] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
     $ DeployDate   : POSIXct[1:22], format: "2018-06-05" ...
     $ Latitude     : num [1:22] 41.6 41.6 41.6 41.6 41.6 ...
     $ Longitude    : num [1:22] -90.4 -90.4 -90.4 -90.4 -90.4 ...
```

I want to add columns that would allow me to summarize this data in a way that I would have the start date of when an animal was in a pool and when the animal moved to a different pool it would have the end date of when it exits.

Ex: Enters Pool 19 on 1/1/22, next detected in Pool 20 on 1/2/22, so there would be columns that say fish entered and exited P[image]ool 19 on 1/1/22 and 1/2/22. I have shared an Excel file example of what I am trying to do. I would like to code upstream movement with a 1 and downstream movement with 0.

I have millions of detections and hundreds of animals that I monitor so I am trying to find a way to look at passages for each animal. Thank you!

Here is my dataset using dput:

```
structure(list(Receiver = c("VR2Tx-480679", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
"VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
"VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
"VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480692", "VR2Tx-480695", 
"VR2Tx-480695", "VR2Tx-480713", "VR2Tx-480713", "VR2Tx-480702", 
"VR100", "VR100", "VR100"), Transmitter = c("A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418"), Species = c("PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
"PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
"PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
"PDFH", "PDFH"), LocalDATETIME = structure(c(1622186212, 1622381700, 
1622384575, 1622184711, 1622381515, 1622381618, 1622381751, 1622381924, 
1622382679, 1622383493, 1622384038, 1622384612, 1622183957, 1622381515, 
1626905954, 1626905688, 1622971975, 1622970684, 1626929618, 1624616880, 
1626084540, 1626954660), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), StationName = c("1405U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", 
"1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", 
"1406U", "1406U", "1404L", "1401D", "1401D", "14Aux2", "14Aux2", 
"15.Mid.Wall", "man_loc", "man_loc", "man_loc"), LengthValue = c(805, 
805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 
805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805), WeightValue = c(8.04, 
8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 
8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04), 
    Sex = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), Translocated = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Pool = c(16, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
    16, 16, 16, 14, 14, 16), DeployDate = structure(c(1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    )), Latitude = c(41.57471, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 
    41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 
    41.5758, 41.57463, 41.5731, 41.5731, 41.57469, 41.57469, 
    41.57469, 41.57469, 41.57469, 41.57469), Longitude = c(-90.39944, 
    -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, 
    -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, 
    -90.39984, -90.40391, -90.40391, -90.40462, -90.40462, -90.40462, 
    -90.40462, -90.40462, -90.40462)), row.names = c(NA, -22L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> dput(T12418)
structure(list(Receiver = c("VR2Tx-480679", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
"VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
"VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
"VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480692", "VR2Tx-480695", 
"VR2Tx-480695", "VR2Tx-480713", "VR2Tx-480713", "VR2Tx-480702", 
"VR100", "VR100", "VR100"), Transmitter = c("A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
"A69-9001-12418"), Species = c("PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
"PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
"PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
"PDFH", "PDFH"), LocalDATETIME = structure(c(1622186212, 1622381700, 
1622384575, 1622184711, 1622381515, 1622381618, 1622381751, 1622381924, 
1622382679, 1622383493, 1622384038, 1622384612, 1622183957, 1622381515, 
1626905954, 1626905688, 1622971975, 1622970684, 1626929618, 1624616880, 
1626084540, 1626954660), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    StationName = c("1405U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", 
    "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", 
    "1406U", "1404L", "1401D", "1401D", "14Aux2", "14Aux2", "15.Mid.Wall", 
    "man_loc", "man_loc", "man_loc"), LengthValue = c(805, 805, 
    805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 
    805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805), WeightValue = c(8.04, 
    8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 
    8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 
    8.04), Sex = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), Translocated = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Pool = c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 14, 14, 16), DeployDate = structure(c(1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
    1528156800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Latitude = c(41.57471, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 
    41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 
    41.5758, 41.57463, 41.5731, 41.5731, 41.57469, 41.57469, 
    41.57469, 41.57469, 41.57469, 41.57469), Longitude = c(-90.39944, 
    -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, 
    -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, 
    -90.39984, -90.40391, -90.40391, -90.40462, -90.40462, -90.40462, 
    -90.40462, -90.40462, -90.40462)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

[image: Animal 12418 data]

Comment: Can you provide the data in a [reproducible format]((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))? You can do `dput(T12418)` in the console, then paste the result into your question?

Comment: I have updated my post!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility for getting the beginning date for entering a pool and ending date for leaving a pool. First, I group by `Species` (could also add additional grouping variables to distinguish between specimens) and arrange by the time. Then, I look for any changes to the `Pool` using `cumsum`. Then, I pull the first date recorded for the pool as the the date that they entered the pool. Then, I do some grouping and ungrouping to grab the date from the next group (i.e., the date the species left the pool) and then copy that date for the whole group. For determining upstream/downstream, we can use `case_when` inside of `mutate`. I'm also assuming that you want this to match the date, so I have filled in the values for each group with the movement for pool change.

```
library(tidyverse)
  
df_dates <- df %>%
  group_by(Species, Transmitter) %>%
  arrange(Species, Transmitter, LocalDATETIME) %>%
  mutate(changeGroup = cumsum(Pool != lag(Pool, default = -1))) %>%
  group_by(Species, Transmitter, changeGroup) %>%
  mutate(EnterPool = first(format(as.Date(LocalDATETIME), "%m/%d/%Y"))) %>%
  ungroup(changeGroup) %>%
  mutate(LeftPool = lead(EnterPool)) %>%
  group_by(Species, Transmitter, changeGroup) %>%
  mutate(LeftPool = last(LeftPool)) %>% 
  ungroup(changeGroup) %>% 
  mutate(stream = case_when((Pool - lag(Pool)) > 0 ~ 0,
                            (Pool - lag(Pool)) < 0 ~ 1)) %>% 
  fill(stream, .direction = "down")
```

**Output**

```
print(as_tibble(df_dates[1:24, c(1:5, 10:17)]), n=24)

# A tibble: 24 × 13
   Receiver     Transmitter    Species LocalDATETIME       StationName  Pool DeployDate          Latitude Longitude changeGroup EnterPool  LeftPool   stream
   <chr>        <chr>          <chr>   <dttm>              <chr>       <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>     <dbl>       <int> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
 1 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-28 06:39:17 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 2 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-28 06:51:51 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 3 VR2Tx-480679 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-28 07:16:52 1405U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 4 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 13:31:55 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 5 VR2Tx-480692 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 13:31:55 1404L          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 6 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 13:33:38 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 7 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 13:35:00 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 8 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 13:35:51 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
 9 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 13:38:44 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
10 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 13:51:19 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
11 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 14:04:53 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
12 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 14:13:58 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
13 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 14:22:55 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
14 VR2Tx-480690 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-05-30 14:23:32 1406U          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
15 VR2Tx-480713 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-06-06 09:11:24 14Aux2         16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
16 VR2Tx-480713 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-06-06 09:32:55 14Aux2         16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           1 05/28/2021 06/25/2021     NA
17 VR100        A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-06-25 10:28:00 man_loc        14 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           2 06/25/2021 07/21/2021      1
18 VR100        A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-07-12 10:09:00 man_loc        14 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           2 06/25/2021 07/21/2021      1
19 VR2Tx-480695 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-07-21 22:14:48 1401D          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           3 07/21/2021 NA              0
20 VR2Tx-480695 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-07-21 22:19:14 1401D          16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           3 07/21/2021 NA              0
21 VR2Tx-480702 A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-07-22 04:53:38 15.Mid.Wall    16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           3 07/21/2021 NA              0
22 VR100        A69-9001-12418 PDFH    2021-07-22 11:51:00 man_loc        16 2018-06-05 00:00:00     41.6     -90.4           3 07/21/2021 NA              0
23 AR100        B80-9001-12420 PDFH    2021-07-22 11:51:00 man_loc        19 2018-06-05 00:00:00     42.6     -90.4           1 07/22/2021 07/22/2021     NA
24 AR100        B80-9001-12420 PDFH    2021-07-22 11:51:01 man_loc        18 2018-06-05 00:00:00     42.6     -90.4           2 07/22/2021 NA              1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Receiver = c("VR2Tx-480679", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
                            "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
                            "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", 
                            "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480690", "VR2Tx-480692", "VR2Tx-480695", 
                            "VR2Tx-480695", "VR2Tx-480713", "VR2Tx-480713", "VR2Tx-480702", 
                            "VR100", "VR100", "VR100", "AR100", "AR100"), Transmitter = c("A69-9001-12418", 
                                                                        "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
                                                                        "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
                                                                        "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
                                                                        "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
                                                                        "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", "A69-9001-12418", 
                                                                        "A69-9001-12418", "B80-9001-12420", "B80-9001-12420"), Species = c("PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
                                                                                                       "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
                                                                                                       "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", 
                                                                                                       "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH", "PDFH"), LocalDATETIME = structure(c(1622186212, 1622381700, 
                                                                                                                                                    1622384575, 1622184711, 1622381515, 1622381618, 1622381751, 1622381924, 
                                                                                                                                                    1622382679, 1622383493, 1622384038, 1622384612, 1622183957, 1622381515, 
                                                                                                                                                    1626905954, 1626905688, 1622971975, 1622970684, 1626929618, 1624616880, 
                                                                                                                                                    1626084540, 1626954660, 1626954661, 1626954660), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               StationName = c("1405U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", 
                               "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", "1406U", 
                               "1406U", "1404L", "1401D", "1401D", "14Aux2", "14Aux2", "15.Mid.Wall", 
                               "man_loc", "man_loc", "man_loc", "man_loc", "man_loc"), LengthValue = c(805, 805, 
                                                                                 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 
                                                                                 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805, 805), WeightValue = c(8.04, 
                                                                                                                                          8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 
                                                                                                                                          8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 8.04, 
                                                                                                                                          8.04, 8.04, 8.04), Sex = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
                                                                                                                                                         "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
                                                                                                                                                         "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), Translocated = c(0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
               Pool = c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
                        16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 14, 14, 16, 18, 19), DeployDate = structure(c(1528156800, 
                                                                                          1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
                                                                                          1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
                                                                                          1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
                                                                                          1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800, 
                                                                                          1528156800, 1528156800, 1528156800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               Latitude = c(41.57471, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 
                            41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 41.5758, 
                            41.5758, 41.57463, 41.5731, 41.5731, 41.57469, 41.57469, 
                            41.57469, 41.57469, 41.57469, 41.57469, 42.57469, 42.57469), Longitude = c(-90.39944, 
                                                                                   -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, 
                                                                                   -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, -90.39793, 
                                                                                   -90.39984, -90.40391, -90.40391, -90.40462, -90.40462, -90.40462, 
                                                                                   -90.40462, -90.40462, -90.40462, -90.40470, -90.40470)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: That is very helpful!! The upstream and downstream refer to the directionality of movement. I am looking at the passage of fish over a dam and I want to use 0 and 1 to signify if the fish moved upstream or downstream over the dam between pool changes. So if a fish moved from pool 14 to pool 15, that would be a downstream passage coded as 0. If a fish moved from pool 15 to pool 14, that would be an upstream passage coded as 1.

Comment: @DominiqueTurney Okay, I understand now. I have updated the answer to include a new column for the upstream/downstream called `stream`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to apply this to my larger dataset with many transmitters and I'm noticing the grouping isn't separating between transmitters. Is there a way to group by transmitters so that the EnterPool and LeftPool doesn't include information on another transmitter?

Comment: @DominiqueTurney Yes, we can just add `Transmitter` as another grouping variable. I have updated the answer to have that. I also added a couple of rows with another transmitter (that I made up) to show how it works.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks again for helping me with this code! It's been amazing!